# Modify dataframe in function not propagated

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function to add extra columns to my dataframe, called as `mpc(sym_time_data, 5, 30, 65)`. In the function, I loop through the arguments to create new columns, however, only the columns from the first run through are kept in the final dataframe - when I print out the columns at each stage, they are all there as expected, but once the function is done, my sym_time_data only has columns with 5 as suffix, and none of the 30 and 65 columns. Is it because of the temporary dataframe and the merge maybe?

```py
def mpc(df, *args):
    print('BEFORE: ', df.columns)
    for i in args:
        ***code to define Hcross, Lcross, Mcross columns 
        ttc = df[[f'Hcross{i}',f'Mcross{i}',f'Lcross{i}']].dropna(how='all') # temp df for calculations
        ttc[f'SigCross{i}'] = np.where(...)
        print('TTC: ', ttc.columns)
        # incorporate into the main dataframe 
        df = df.merge(ttc[f'SigCross{i}'], how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
        print('IN LOOP: ', df.columns)
    print('AFTER: ', df.columns)
```

Comment: Do the columns with suffix 30 and 65 appear in the print inside the for loop?

Comment: The columns are all there when I run the code with the merge line commented out. :( But I need the merge because ttc is of different length than df

Comment: Yes, all the columns appear in the prints inside the loop!

Comment: Maybe it's because you have no common index to merge on?

Comment: When I wrote it on the command line, the merge worked as expected. ttc is created from df, so the index (multiindex) is the same. It is weird that I get columns with suffix 5, and all the numbers in those columns are as expected.

Comment: Where does the function return the final dataframe?  Where is `return df`? (and please fix the indentation of your code)

Comment: there is no return line, I just call the function and expect it to add the columns to the dataframe I passed in. The indentation is something with the stackoverlow, it is there in the raw code segment that I see in the edit window, but gone in the preview.

Comment: Thank you Julien for the code indentation edit

Comment: This function will _not_ work inplace on the dataframe because of reassignment, i.e. `df = df.merge(...)`.  Once the function exits, the newly merged `df` goes out of scope and is lost. You must return `df` from this function, then call it via `df = mpc(df, ...)`.  Also, rather than `merge`, consider `join`:  `df = df.join(ttc[f'SigCross{i}'])`

Answer (score 0):

Because the merge line was the issue, I ended up creating another temporary dataframe to perform the merge, which then resulted in the simple column assignment to my main dataframe.

```
df_dummy = df[[f'Hcross{i}', f'Mcross{i}', f'Lcross{i}']]
df_dummy = df_dummy.merge(ttc[f'SigCross{i}'], how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
df[f'SigCross{i}'] = df_dummy[f'SigCross{i}']
```